# Scan For Multiple File Exentions and Copy To New Dir If Found

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, recursion, file-search

I am using `Ubuntu` and I am needing to recursively search a directory and subs for any `.mp4`, `.mkv`, or `.wav` files.  I saw that `mmv` may be my best solution, but I can not get the syntax correct.  So how would I convert this to search for an array of file names, or would I just want to run 3 iterations for each file extension I am after?

I was using the tutorial here to write this, so please forgive me if I am way outta line
[find all m3](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-find-move-all-mp3-file.html)

```
# find / -iname "*.mp4"  -type f -exec mv {} ./Downloads/Media Files \;
```

Comment: Instead of `find /` you might need something like `find /path/to/dir/` or `find .` (for current directory).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU bash 4:

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob
mv -v **/*.{mp4,mkv,wav} ./Downloads/Media Files
```

---

> `globstar`: If  set,  the  pattern ** used in a pathname expansion context will match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories. If the pattern is followed by a /, only  directories  and subdirectories match.
>
> `nullglob`: If set, bash allows patterns which match no files (see Pathname Expansion) to expand to a null string, rather than themselves.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\(` and `-o` (or):

```
find / -type f \( -iname "*.mp4" -o -iname "*.mkv" -o -iname "*.wav" \) -exec mv {} ./Downloads/Media Files \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace -iname with -regex. Regex understands emacs regular expressions by default (but you can change this behaviour using -regextype):

```
find / -regex ".*\.mp4\|.*\.mkv\|.*\.wav" ...
```

Learn the power of reguar expressions, it will open a new universe of power!